# Where is Raspberry Pi "wastebasket" located in the file system?

Tags: raspbian, linux, pi-4, filesystem

I am trying to understand the Raspbian file system better. I opened properties on the Raspberry Pi's "Wastebasket" hoping to find out where it is located in the file system and I found `trash:///`.

Can anyone explain this, please?
I expected to find some folder off of root e.g. `/some-dir/trash`.

System info: Raspberry Pi 4B
OS: Raspbian Buster

Comment: Hello and welcome to this community. Add the RPi model and the OS you have installed. Also, you should explain your purpose to get a better answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The folder trash can is in `/home/pi/.local/share/Trash/`. In this folder, there are two folders, `files` and `info`.

```
/home/pi/.local/share/Trash/files/  

/home/pi/.local/share/Trash/info/
```

[*Source*](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=129962#p868222)

Comment: Can you add to your answer how/why that's linked from `trash:///`?

Comment: @Mast https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/107423/44221

Answer (score 11):

You can find it at: `/home/pi/.local/share/Trash/`.

The `trash://` prefix comes from [`gvfs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/gvfs-trash.1.html) (GNOME Virtual File System) / the [XDG Spec](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/trash-spec). It does map to an actual filesystem path, but the idea is that applications don't need to know it if they use a certain platform like `gvfs`.

It also looks friendlier to users, like the 'Recycling Bin' on Windows.

Answer (score 8):

It has one, but it also does not...

On one hand there is not concept of a trash bin/wastebasket on Linux, especially when dealing with the shell. `rm` deletes (more or less) for good.

But on the other hand there IS a trash specification that most Desktop Environments use (like KDE and xfce), published by freedesktop. When you delete things using the GUI they will be shown in `trash:///`, but the actual location is for the most part `~/.local/share/Trash` which has two sub-directories:

- `files` which stores the actual files
- `info` which contains information to the files, such as

  - original filename/path
  - size

There is a pitfall though: when you have another filesystem, such as a USB stick or an external HDD, the implementation of the specification is permitted to also store a trash directory in the filesystem's root directory (so if you mounted your USB in `/mnt/usb/` it would be that fs' root directory) with the name `Trash-XXXX` where `XXXX` is your user id.

Another, slightly less common thing is that the main Trash directory is dependent on the `$XDG_DATA_DIR` environment variable.

For more information on the spec: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/trash-spec/trashspec-latest.html

But can't I put things into the trash from the Shell? You may ask.
Well, yes but the only implementation that is not dependent on the desktop environment you are using, that I found, was a seemingly unmaintained python implementation with quirks like entering an infinite loop with no feedback to the user when certain operations fail. So it's not really suited for scripting purposes, maybe passable for interactive sessions.

Here is its GitHub repo: https://github.com/andreafrancia/trash-cli